# Cloning and replacing a HD. The full story

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, clone, enclosures

I have an XP machine with 1 drive partitioned as: C, D, E, F and want to make an exact copy of it.

1. Run some HD cloning software and clone the original drive.
2. Physically remove/replace the HD in the machine.

Why do I see COUNTLESS examples about doing the extremely easy steps 1 and 2...
but can't find anything about the odd and complex #3?

3. My new drive is NOT an 'exact' clone, it is incorrectly marked as: G, H, I, J.

How can I get it to be: C, D, E, F like everyone would expect?

(I used 'EaseUS ToDo BackUp' for my partition cloning and don't want to re-cloning it yet again, just to fix this problem.   I need a solution for this issue... starting from the mess I'm in now.)

Comment: how did you clone the drive?  It is plugged into the same SATA port that the original drive was plugged into?

Comment: If both drives are connected to the system that's what will happen because 2 drives can't have the same letter. In disk management you can right click a partition to change the drive letter

Answer (score 1):

What program or method are you using for cloning? Regardless, your getting "G,H,I,J" because the method you're using detects the current "C,D,E,F" drive and partitions. Windows doesn't allow partitions/drives to have the same letter.

You can easily change drive letters by disconnecting the current drive that is assigned C,D,E,F. Loading Disk Management (Run > `DiskMgmt.msc`), right-click the G,H,I,J drive, then select Change Drive Letter.

You can also change drive letters using Diskpart (cmd > `diskpart`):
~ `list volume`
~ `select volume X` (where X is the G,H,I,J partitions)
~ `drive letter=X` (Where X is each partition being assigned/changed to C,D,E,F respectively)

Alternatively you can use a, non Windows oriented, cloning software that doesn't pay as much attention to drive letters. Here's a couple of my favorites. [P.I.N.G](http://ping.windowsdream.com/), [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php), [HDClone5](http://www.miray.de/download/sat.hdclone.html)

Comment: I used EaseUS ToDo BackUp to do the partition cloning.  How does someone just "disconnect the current drive"?   Where is the "disconnect" method?  (C,D,E,F is the windows drive.)